# Simple, but correct equation gives "Error, "-" unexpected" in Maple

Tags: maple

I have the (very simple) equation in Maple:

```
x := ((1 + ((-4.5) + (-2.6))))
```

However, although everything should be correct, I get the following error message by Maple: *Error, "-" unexpected*.

If I remove the minus sign in front of the 4.5, the error disappears and x is calculated as expected. If I remove the minus sign in front of the 2.6 however, the error persists.

Note: I have to work with equations like this, i.e. I want to be able to use such equations with redundant braces (removing unneeded braces is not an option for my application).

**Question**: What is happening here? And how can I fix that error?

Edit: Maple Version is 16, Win 7, problem exists in both 2D math mode and 1D plain text maple input entered via the standard GUI (input mode doesn't seem to make any difference).

Comment: Are you sure the `-` is a standard hyphen? Try deleting the one in front of the `4.5` and replacing it by typing it in on your keyboard. If you copy/pasted this from an external source it might not be the dash you think it is.

Comment: @Bucket Yes, I am sure, I even wrote the equation completly by hand using just the standard +/- on my keybord but the error persists. If I remove "enough" braces, the error disappears, so I think it is somehow related to the redundant braces. The braces however are correct, as the error also disappears if I just change the sign of the -4.5.

Comment: You did not provide details as the Maple version, which interface, and which input mode, which is not helpful. I get no problem if I copy and paste that into Maple 2018's Standard GUI, either as 1D plaintext Maple notation or as typeset 2D Math input. And no problems with entering that as plaintext into the commandline interface. Presumably you are using the Standard GUI? If you are using 2D Math input then it is wrong to show it here as plaintext. In that case upload the worksheet that has the problem somewhere, eg, in a question at www.mapleprimes.com which is Maple's user forum.

Comment: everythings works  well  in Maple18..and it is not equation

Comment: @acer I updated the question with all the information.

Comment: I see the problem using 2D Input in Maple 16.02, but I don't see the problem in that version when using 1D input in that version. I don't understand what you mean by "work with such equations". These brackets are ephemeral, in the sense that they are only part of the input and the parser dispenses with them. So "work with them" means what, other that that someone needs to manually enter the input containing them. But then how is is part of some other application?

Comment: @acer These are auto-generated equations which are built by some other application. I then want to further process these equations with Maple. In theory, I could "fix" them by removing all those redundant braces. However, this is not feasible because I have a lot such equations and the equations are much more complex than the example here. Also, I would like to understand whats the problem, because syntactically, the equations are prefectly fine (as you said, the parser should eliminated them).

Comment: As mentioned, I don't see the problem with plaintext input in my Maple 16.02. I cannot see how some equation generated by another program could be inserted into Maple in 2D Input unless done manually -- in which case why not do it into 1D input?! I doubt anyone here's going to debug the Library side of 2D input parser (on the off chance the problem is there and not in the Java GUI), about an old version's bug (not present in Maple 2018). But l've lost interest, since you don't seem at all willing to answer exactly *how* it's input into Maple. Have you tried to `parse` it as a plaintext string?

Comment: @acer Well, as I already said I enter the input via the standard GUI (also via 1D input, as also already stated). However, I found a workaround which I posted as an answer. A "real" solution instead of a workaround would still be appreciated, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem apparently only exists in document mode. There, it doesn't matter if 1D or 2D Maple Input is used, it always gives an error for the above posted equation. It is maybe also related to floating point tokens only, as the error also disapears when using -4 instead of -4.5.

When using worksheet mode instead of document mode, the error also doesn't appear anymore, so I will just worksheet mode instead of document mode as a workaround.